# Solving Boundary Value with bvp4c Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, ode

i'm trying to solve a boundary value problem of an system `q' = f(q(t), a(t))` with an input `a` using bvp4c in Matlab. Where `q = [q1, q2, q1_dot, q2_dot]'`

My Matlab Code does not work properly. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[img: System Equation of the One Pendulum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWROk.png)

`a` is a input function.

the initial state: `q1(0) = pi, q2(0) = 0, q1_dot(0) = 0, q2_dot(0) = 0.`

the end state: `q1(te) = 0, q2(te) = 0, q1_dot(te) = 0, q2_dot(te) = 0.`

input initial state: `a(0) = 0,` and the end state: `a(te) = 0`.

i've in total 10 boundaries. one_pendulum_bc can take only 5 and not more and fewer.

```
function one_pendulum

options = [];    % place holder
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,1,1000),[pi, 0, 0, 0],0);

sol = bvp4c(@one_pendulum_ode,@one_pendulum_bc,solinit,options);
t = sol.x;
plot(t, sol.y(1,:))
figure(2)
plot(t, sol.y(2,:))
figure(3)
plot(t, sol.y(3,:))
figure(4)
plot(t, sol.y(4,:))

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------

function dydx = one_pendulum_ode(x,y,a)
% Parameter of the One-Pendulum
m1 = 0.3583;    % weight of the pendulum [kg]
J1 = 0.03799;   % moment of inertia [Nms^2]
a1 = 0.43;      % center of gravity [m]
d1 = 0.006588;  % coefficient of friction [Nms]
g  = 9.81;      % gravity [m/s^2]

dydx = [ y(3)
         y(4)
        (a*a1*m1*cos(y(1)) + a1*g*m1*sin(y(1)) - d1*y(3))/(J1 + a1^2 *m1)
         a ];

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function res = one_pendulum_bc(ya,yb,a)
res = [ya(1) - pi
       ya(2)
       ya(4)
       yb(1)
       yb(3)];
```

[img: The result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkC2.gif)

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about your problem: What does not work properly? Is the output not what you expected? Does the code throw an error? And if so, what command does cause it and what is the error message?

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Sorry for my poor English. I'm not getting any error message, It's just the output that i not expected. The output is wrong.

Comment: A two, second-order differential equations  need only four boundary conditions to be unique; more than four makes the problem over-determined.  You're over-specifying the problem.

Comment: This looks more like an optimal control problem where the additional boundary conditions are absorbed by the infinite degrees of freedom of the unknown function `a(t)`. You can parametrize `a` as a linear combination of suitable kernel functions and add the constants to the system as functions with derivatives zero. This however is not the optimal way to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for reply, @LutzL It's a feedforward control problem. `a(t) = g(t, q)`. The Examples of the bvp4c are only for systems without input like       `y' = f(t, q)`

Comment: @TroyHaskin the states have 8 boandaries, the input 2. How can it take only half of them?

Comment: pls see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPkC2.gif

Comment: Then it is still an optimal control problem. Your aim is to design the control function `g`. This has infinitely many degrees of freedom. You can add additional restrictions on the control function that reduce that dimension.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the hint. You are right that `a = g(t, q)` has infinitely many degrees of freedom. In my Matlab Code is `g` a constant.

Comment: To swing a pendulum around from the stable to the instable stationary point is a task that requires fine-tuning. Obviously, accelerating the anchor point with a constant force will have difficulty in achieving that.

Comment: can someone tell me, how should the initial solution be chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solved it with a model function.

```
function one_pendulum

options = bvpset('stats', 'on', 'NMax', 3000);


T = 2.5;

sol0 = [
-5.3649
119.5379
-187.3080
91.6670];

solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0, T, T/0.002),[pi, 0, 0, 0], sol0);

sol = bvp4c(@one_pendulum_ode,@one_pendulum_bc,solinit,options, T);
t = sol.x;

ax1 = subplot(2,2,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,2,2);
ax3 = subplot(2,2,3);
ax4 = subplot(2,2,4);

plot(ax1, t, sol.y(1,:))
title(ax1, 'phi');
plot(ax2, t, sol.y(2,:))
title(ax2, 'x');
plot(ax3, t, sol.y(3,:))
title(ax3, 'phi_d');
plot(ax4, t, sol.y(4,:))
title(ax4, 'x_d');

length = size(t)

k = sol.parameters
for i=1:length(2)
   k5 = -(k(1) * sin(pi) + k(2) * sin(2*pi)  + k(3) * sin(3*pi) +    k(4) * sin(4*pi))/sin(5*pi);
x = t(i);
acc(i)=k(1) * sin(pi*x/T) + k(2) * sin(2*pi*x/T)  + k(3) * sin(3*pi*x/T) + k(4) * sin(4*pi*x/T) + k5* sin(5*pi*x/T);
  end

figure(2)
plot(t,acc)

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------

function dydx = one_pendulum_ode(x,y,k,T)
% Parameter of the One-Pendulum
m1 = 0.3583;    % weight of the pendulum [kg]
J1 = 0.03799;   % moment of inertia [Nms^2]
a1 = 0.43;      % center of gravity [m]
d1 = 0.006588;  % coefficient of friction [Nms]
g  = 9.81;      % gravity [m/s^2]

% Ansatzfunktion 
k5 = -(k(1) * sin(pi) + k(2) * sin(2*pi)  + k(3) * sin(3*pi) + k(4) *      sin(4*pi))/sin(5*pi);
a =    k(1) * sin(pi*x/T) + k(2) * sin(2*pi*x/T)  + k(3) *    sin(3*pi*x/T) + k(4) * sin(4*pi*x/T) + k5* sin(5*pi*x/T);

dydx = [ y(3)
     y(4)
     (a*a1*m1*cos(y(1)) + a1*g*m1*sin(y(1)) - d1*y(3))/(J1 + a1^2 *m1)
     a ];

  % --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function res = one_pendulum_bc(ya,yb,k,T)
 res = [ya(1) - pi
   ya(2)
   ya(3)
   ya(4)
   yb(1)
   yb(2)
   yb(3)
   yb(4)];
```